# Get a key by value from a list in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to get a key from a dict, but the corresponding value is a list and I only have one value (one element) of the list. I already found

```
mydict = {'george':[(16,16), 17],'amber':19}
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index((16,16))])
```

but this doesn't work, as it produces an value error because of the target value being only one element of the list.

How can I get the key only using one element of the list (using only the (16,16)?

Comment: Try: [(16, 16), 17] instead of `(16,16)`

Comment: Your example is weird - what do you want to print? The value of the key 'george' ? The first element of the value of  'george' ? Please go over [dictionarys](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and play around with them. The key whichs value-lists first value is (16,16) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you're missing is how to find a given value in a list: it's the `in` operator.

```
target = (16, 16)
mydict = {'george':[(16,16), 17],'amber':19}
[k for k, v in mydict.items() if type(v) == list and target in v]
```

This is the long way to write the comprehension and filter, but it makes the steps obvious.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Dictionarys are great if you need a value by key, not so great the other way around. You can always iterate over the dicts items:

```
mydict = {'george':[(16,16), 17],'amber':19}

for key,val in mydict.items(): # decomposed tuple of key,value
    if isinstance(val,list) and val[0] == (16,16): # check if value a list and 1st elem ok
        print (key) # print key
```

Doku:  [dictionarys](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using only a part of the list?
Small modification in your code:

```
print(list(mydict.keys())[list(mydict.values()).index([(16, 16), 17])])
```

prints george as expected.
Works with python 3.6.0

Comment: Im sorry i was too vague, I edited the question so you can understand what I meant

Comment: More precise after the edition :) So I think @Prune answer is the one you're looking for.